# iframe content not available in JavaScript during onload

Tags: jquery, angularjs, iframe

I am integrating a payment service provider with 3Ds, one of the steps comes with following instructions:

1. The response to your initial API request will contain an url and some data. Put a hidden iframe on your website. Set its target to the url you received and do a POST
2. The code that renders in the iframe will do some stuff and then redirect by making a POST a "notification url" you provided (in the initial request).
3. Listen for this redirect, and when it happens make a Resume call to the API.

I even got a code sample from the PSP.
So I did just that, it all works, the iframe is redirected to the notification url I provided, the html served by that url is rendered in the iframe.

However the problems begin when I want to verify that the content rendered in the iframe is what I expect. I need this because the code I originally rendered in the iframe can do multiple redirects before redirecting to the notification url. Step 2 of the 3Ds process actually does that. And every time that happens the onLoad handler is triggered.

Here's what the iframe initially looks like:

```
<iframe id="hidden_iframe" name="hidden_iframe" style="width: 0; height: 0; border: 0; border: none; position: absolute;">
        <HTML>
        <div id="HELLO"><B>HIDDEN FRAME... </B></div>
    </HTML>
</iframe>
```

And here's the html my notification url returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div id = "threeDSMethodData" name = "threeDSMethodData"> PROCESSING...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried just returning a div, but the browsers were complaining about it.

The code sample has the following code for testing if the iframe contains what is expected:

```
 if ($("#hidden_iframe").contents().find("#threeDSMethodData").html()!=undefined) {
```

I'm fairly sure my html is rendered, because the POST call to my notification url is successful and returns the html. Also when I inspect the iframe in the browser I see the following:
[image]

But in the onLoad method the above expression is undefined. I've put a breakpoint in the onLoad handler, and from the context of the function it looks like the iframe contains the original content (with the  div)
[image]
yet at the same time the element inspector shows me the result of the notification url POST (what you see in the first picture).

My UI is built on AngularJS, so I'm hooking up my onLoad the Angular way:

```
var hiddenFrame = angular.element("#hidden_iframe");
            hiddenFrame.on("load", function () {
                console.log("hidden iframe load was called");
                if (hiddenFrame.contents().find("#threeDSMethodData").html() != undefined) { // this test fails
                        console.log("hidden iframe test passed");
...
```

When that didn't work I also tried with jQuery:

```
$("#hidden_iframe").on("load", function () {
        console.log("hidden iframe load was called - the JQUERY WAY!");
        if ($("#hidden_iframe").contents().find("#threeDSMethodData").html() != undefined) { // also undefined here
            console.log("hidden iframe test passed");
```

...

in addition to not working, the jQuery code also caused my website to start reloading in a loop, causing the onLoad method to be hit endlessly :/

What am I doing wrong? Is there another (better) way to do this?

EDIT: I have since tried the most basic way of hooking up the onLoad method:

```
document.getElementById("hidden_iframe").onload = function () {
            console.log("hidden iframe load was called");
```

yet the result in the debugger is the same. Interestingly, I managed to get this in the console:

```
var b = document.getElementById('threeDSMethodData')
b
```

[image]

though only in Chrome, not in Firefox. And that's the only way the console will acknowledge that the new content is there. Everything else on the object other than this printout - innerHtml, innerText, ChildNodes, still claims there's only the original div.
I've also tried to find a different event to hook into. There isn't any. I found something called 'onloadend' but that's deprecated and not supported in Chrome. Please help :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem was CORS policy.
The PSP endpoint doesn't allow localhost links for the notification urls, so I had to supply links to UAT. And since I was dev-testing on localhost, and the iframe was POSTing to UAT, it had a different origin and its content was blocked by CORS policy.

When I tried with the site and the notification url on the same domain, the aforementioned test

```
if (hiddenFrame.contents().find("#threeDSMethodData").html() != undefined)
```

worked just fine. I can't believe how much time I've wasted on this and how many neurons I fried in the process...